# Use an array of values for a slider

Tags: arrays, slider, viewer

I want to use an array of id, for my little slider-viewer I'm building. I just want to display multiple things using 2 buttons next and previous.

For now I use something like this, using only 2 url id, but I need at least 20 urlid in my viewer :

```
var urlid1 = 'd3885ca76ac54e958c2855a4fbd3dbf3';
var urlid2 = '3aa64527d1614998b4812bfefbbc896a';


function Next() {
    client.init( urlid2 );
}

function Previous() {
    client.init( urlid1 ); }
```

So I've never use an array before, and the things I tried didn't work. Do you know a proper way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems straight forward enough

```
var index = 0;
var array = ["url1", "url2", "url3", ...]

function next() {
    index++;
    if(index > array.length) {
        index = 0;
    }
    client.init(array[index]);
}

function previous() {
    index--;
    if(index < 0) {
        index = array.length;
    }
    client.init(array[index]);
}
```

It may be better practice to actually refactor those changes to the index variable to other functions to enable reuse, but this should give you an idea of how it is done.

If client is something that you have wrote then you might want to look at the naming of your functions, init is normally reserved for instantiating the class as new, from your example you seem to be changing a resource so you may want a function name like client.show(); or client.update();

Comment: It works ! There is some things I need to fix tho : the index is [0] but when I push Next, it loads the [0] again, then the [1], [2] ... I don't understand why it loads the [0]

Comment: If thats the case then switch around the index incrementing with the init, so you do the index++ and check it hasn't exceeded its bounds before running client.init()

Comment: Thank's for your help Varedis but I'm totally a beginner and I didn't get what you're trying to explain me here..

Answer (score 0):

Thank's Varedis.

Final code is :

```
var index = 0;
var array = ["0e4b4e0789bf41c7b05129a76de0abb0","3aa64527d1614998b4812bfefbbc896a","d3885ca76ac54e958c2855a4fbd3dbf3","8f927023e10c40b9b22d3c13df7c08aa"];

client.init(array[index]);

function next() {
    index++;
    if(index >= array.length) {
        index = 0;
    }
    client.init(array[index]);
}

function previous() {
    index--;
    if(index < 0 ) {


        index = array.length-1;
    }
    client.init(array[index]);
}
```

I had to use " index = array.length-1; " but I can't explain it. You know why ? How index could be 5 if I only have 4 values ?